# Prestashop Mobile view not working

Tags: prestashop-1.6

I am trying to solve a problem for a client who updated his prestashop to 1.6 and now the mobile view isn't working? the web site works fine but not the mobile view. i followed this [toto](https://www.templatemonster.com/help/prestashop-1-5-x1-6-x-troubleshooter-theme-does-not-show-up-on-mobile-devices.html#prettyPhoto) which shows how to reactivate but nothing changed, any help ?

Answer (score 0):

The Prestashop 1.6 default theme uses responsive bootstrap. The question is. Does your client use the 1.5 or 1.6 theme? Watch this. Change the theme to the default Prestashop 1.6 and then check the mobile view. Do you have the mobile view activated or do you use a responsive theme?